# Is there an easy way to to send a simple GET request from a lock screen widget?

Tags: app-widgets, lock-screen-widgets

I've built a garage door opener that can be triggered by a GET request (with the appropriate password, of course), and right now it's controlled by a webpage with javascript. It's possible to use this page from my phone to open the door, but it's quite a hassle to get to my browser before I can use it. What I'm after is a home screen or lock screen widget that will send off the request with the touch of a button, or an easy way to create one. I've attempted to write android apps before, and found it all very cumbersome.

I have a Nexus 5, running the latest cm-11 nightly build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be achieved with [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker): You can create a "task" performing the `HTTP_GET` you need, and then create a shortcut to that task on your homescreen (the same way you'd create any other shortcut there: *Tasker Task* shows up in the list of available shortcuts, and lets you select the task to create the shortcut for).

Comment: Not only looks perfect, also looks great for tinkering around with, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh yes, definitely! Just follow up to the questions carrying the Tasker-tag. Or see my [collection of Tasker resources](http://www.androidpit.de/de/android/forum/thread/435917/) for more :)